# How to create a model with submodels?

Tags: database, resource-model

I have 4 tables:
Animals 
-- Race 
---- Color 
-------- Name

I know how I can load each table one by one but since the tables are related I want to load all elements and the whole hierarchy at once.

I tried loading in _afterLoad but this would result in executing many queries

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Implement your own Resource model, extended somehow from `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract` and change `_getLoadSelect()`, then you can load whatever you want